# ASP.NET plugin architecture without using reflection or static constructors?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reflection, plugins, web-config

I have an ASP.NET HttpModule that is distributed as a DLL. I badly need a plugin architecture so I can isolate some heavyweight, rarely used features into external .dlls, and speed up/slim up the core functionality.

I've experimented with (1) reflection and (2) static constructors.

It seems GoDaddy and a few other web hosts prohibit use of Reflection, making #1 useless.

.NET 4.0 now calls static constructors lazily, eliminating #2.

Any other ideas? How can I have a generic plugin registration system that doesn't require C# or VB code to register the plugins? Even a web.config plugin registration list would be fine, but I don't know how to do that without using reflection.

Update: I need this to work in .NET 2.0 as well as higher versions

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for extensibility?

Parts of it do use reflection, but you can also use it without reflection at all - see [this](http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=71640) forum post for details.